# How to limit the amount of data for each user in a MySQL table and automatically delete the oldest data

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a web application where I want to save and display the 10 most recent pages viewed by the user for the user, and I can only come up with everytime a user view a page, the page will insert a data into a MySQL table called 'recentview', then I will call the data and display it as recently viewed pages in the user interface.

Now the problem is I want to limit the number of entries for each user to 10 inside the MySQL table, and when a user visited the 11th page, the table should automatically delete the oldest data for that particular user, so there must always been max of 10 entries for each user inside the table.

So far I have been searching through the web and most I could find are people asking how to limit the data entries for the whole table, while what I'm looking for is limiting the entries for each user.

So far here is the PHP code :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');

$email= $_COOKIE['email'];

$recentsql = "INSERT INTO recent (email, page) VALUES ('email', 'page1')";
$recentquery = mysqli_query($con, $recentsql);

$countsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recent WHERE email='$email'";
$countquery = mysqli_query($con,$countsql);
$countrow = mysqli_fetch_array($countquery);
$count = $countrow[0];

if ($count > 10) {
  //php codes here to delete the oldest entries for this particular user($_COOKIE['email'])//
  //I could not figure out what is the code to do this task, please help//
}

?>
```

All helps and better suggestions are very much appreciated. Thx

OK, I apologize if my question is not very clear, so here is an example of what the MySQL table looks like :
*I classified my user id by their e-mail address

```
PID   email             recentpage
1     user1@user1.com   page1
2     user1@user1.com   some other page
3     user1@user1.com   other page
4     user1@user1.com   page2
5     user1@user1.com   some more page
6     user1@user1.com   more page
7     user1@user1.com   pages
8     user1@user1.com   different page
9     user1@user1.com   still different page
10    user1@user1.com   page in the web

11    user2@user2.com   page1
12    user2@user2.com   other page
13    user2@user2.com   still different page
```

so what I want is set a limit for each user (i.e user1@user1.com & user2@user2.com, etc) to only 10 recentpage data in the table, and if they visit another new different page, it will delete the oldest entries, in this case for user1@user.com, "page1" and insert the newest visited page in the table, hope this makes my question clearer. Thx for helps.

Comment: It's rather quite simple. Instead of deleting if there's more than 10, check first if the user already has 10. If there isn't, let the INSERT do its thing. If not, then just echo a message or redirect the user.

Comment: What is the name of this column `$countrow[0]`, is it "email", or "id", other? I hope you're reading this comment, otherwise I can't help you. Plus, it would make it a lot easier if you had a date/time column.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$countrow[0]` is `$countrow['COUNT(*)']`.

Comment: @Verhaeren Ok thanks. I thought `[0]` was a column/row name. Usually the first column is reserved for an "id". I've come up with a solution of sorts, but I can't/won't put it in until I know exactly what I'm dealing with, in regards to row names. OP would be better off using a column with a date/time type, TBH. It would be sooOOoooo much simpler/easier. At this point in time, OP can hire a developer. I value my time very much.

Comment: I don' need to use column with date/time is because I already use primary ID column (PID) and it is already in order of the latest entry, so I don't think I need date/time column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not hundred percent sure if I get what you want but I think this would do it:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');

    $email= $_COOKIE['email'];

    $countsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recent WHERE email='$email'";
    $countquery = mysqli_query($con,$countsql);
    $countrow = mysqli_fetch_array($countquery);
    $count = $countrow[0];

    if ($count == 10) {
        $deletesql = "DELETE FROM `recent` WHERE `id` = (SELECT `id` FROM (SELECT id FROM `recent` WHERE `email` = '$email' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1) as t)"; 
        $deletesql_res = mysqli_query($con, $deletesql);
    }

    $recentsql = "INSERT INTO recent (email, page) VALUES ('email', 'page1')";
    $recentquery = mysqli_query($con, $recentsql);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to delete everything except the 10 most recent emails

```
$query = "delete from recent
where email = '$email'
and id not in (
    select id from recent
    where email = '$email'
    order by id desc limit 10
)";
```

Comment: Thx for the help, I am going to try to test this now, but if I understand correctly, won't this delete 10 records at once ? sorry if my question is unclear, what I want is to delete 1 oldest record when there is a new record and the record for that user exceeds 10. thx again

Comment: I tried this and it does nothing, turns out it returns an error 'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery', I am using xampp 1.8.3, php 5.5.11

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to show 10 most recent pages without deleting all the previous records. In the query `id` is the primary key of your table

```
SELECT * FROM recent WHERE email='$email' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Re-read the question. The OP wants to delete data.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question. It's only the suggestion just that can also track the previous records of the users.

Comment: thx for the suggestion, I thought about this, but then it will really make the table really full with unused data (i.e if a user visited 100 pages, it will all be inside the table but only 10 are displayed, 90 data are unused..)

Comment: Weird, it returns "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery", I am using xampp 1.8.3, php 5.5.11, will try to find a way to update mysql then

Answer (score 0):

If you have $count records in your table, you can retain the last 10 by deleting $count - 10

```
$limit = $count-10    ;
$deletesql = "DELETE * from recent ORDER by id LIMIT $limit";
$deletequery = mysqli_query($con,$deletesql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a batch job periodically and it should be cabable to delete oldest data